# Fully uninstall X server

Tags: server, apt, xorg, uninstall, lxde

I was playing around with the x server and LXDE in ubuntu server and installed it using the command `sudo apt-get install xorg lubuntu-desktop`. When I went to uninstall it, by using the command `sudo apt-get remove xorg lubuntu-desktop --purge` then `sudo apt-get autoremove`, I notice that the space freed up is less than the amount installed. Also, I still have some files and commands left over from X such as `startx` and `lxde-session`. How do I get rid of these?

The computer also boots up as lubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

Test this:

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan

aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(lubuntu),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu))))'

apt-get dist-upgrade
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Comment: I liked this and used it on a 20.04/5.4.0-73-generic thumbdrive system as a last resort (installed xinit instead of xauth).  But it left the network inoperable and had removed all the usual tools for fixing it like iproute2,netplan.io,etc...